# okhttp Dispatcher throws executor rejected

Tags: okhttp

I am using Okhttp Dispatcher in my application to send out HTTP2 request to a simulator which is an Reactor Netty HTTPSever . Actually we are doing a PT with 10 simulators , out of which 9 simulators have a delay of 50 ms , things work fine in this case , but when i introduce the 10th simulator with 10 seconds delay then immediately all of the requests are failing with executor rejected error response. Below is the dispatcher configuration used

Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher(new ThreadPoolExecutor(
1,
350,
60L,
TimeUnit.SECONDS,
new SynchronousQueue(),
Util.threadFactory(HTTP_THREAD_NAME_DEFAULT, false)));

```
        dispatcher.setMaxRequestsPerHost(300);
        dispatcher.setMaxRequests(500);
```

I have tried increasing the ThreadPoolExecutor max threads to 500  , MaxRequestsPerHost to 500 and  MaxRequests to 800, but things don't work

NOTE: we are testing with 4k tps and its an springboot application not mobile application

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp uses the parameters `maxRequests` and `maxRequestsPerHost` to determine concurrency. You should keep the default dispatcher and use these tuning parameters instead.

Comment: Thanks for the solution it worked, now I am not getting executor rejected after changing to default Dispatcher.  But I am not able to fine tune these parameters for my requirement where I have to support 8k tps out of which 90% of requests  should wait for 50ms delay and 10% for 10 sec delay 
I have tried setting both of them to 800 , this is resolving executor rejected issue but the memory allocated is getting filled up very fast leading to OOM because of 10 sec delay , can you please help in fine tuning the parameters